# Mysql db design users, teams, groups

Tags: mysql, database-design, normalization

I have 3 tables users, teams, groups. Every team can have multiple groups. In every group there is one or more user. User can be in multiple groups. Do you think it would be better to use group for all users (so every team would have at least one group called *all users*) or to introduce another table team_user *(id, user_id, team_id)*?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by

> Do you think it would be better to use group for all users (so every team would have at least one group called all users)

But I would agree with your "or" part of the sentence anyway.

If a user can belong to multiple groups, and groups can contain multiple users, then you have a many to many relationship, which can best be described in 3 tables when looking at normalization.

```
User
----
userId PK

Group
----
groupId PK
teamId -- assumption here, you said a team can have multiple groups, i was interpreting that as a group can't belong to multiple teams.

Team
----
teamiD PK

user_group
----
userId PK
groupId PK
```

or

```
user_group -- unique constraint on userId/groupId
----
id PK
userId 
groupId
```

Comment: So do you think the table team_user in not necessary? What if a user do not belong to any group, but I need him to be part of a team?

Comment: you didn't state any relationship (at least not that i saw) in your question about users and teams... you stated that users can belong to groups, and that groups can be part of a team.  Users are related to teams only through their group association - if it is different than that, perhaps elaborate on your requirements or point out what I missed in them.

Comment: Sorry that I wasn't more clear. I want that user belongs to a team. But not every user of a team needs to be part of a group. I have 2 options. 1. was presented by Philip. 2. options is to assign at least one group to a team and call it e.g. allTeamUsers?

Answer (score 0):

Personaly i would prefer an extra team_user relation. 
But in the end it doesnt make a big difference: 
If you dont have it you need somethink to identify the "all yousers group" for every team and make sure ther is exactly one for every group. (Ore maybe 0 if Teams can have 0 Users. Witch would be a problem with "In every group there is one or more user.") In both ways you have to make sure that if you add a User(A),Group(B) to USER_GROUP relation that "User is in Team" also is true. (I think the constraints for that will look better with an extra relation but both is possible.)

So i would have thes DB Schema: PK = Part of Primary Key, FK = Foreign Key

```
USER
user_id PK
```

--

```
GROUP
group_id PK
team_id FK (becaus n Groups to 1 Team.)
```

--

```
TEAM
team_id PK
```

relations:

```
USER_TEAM
user_id PK FK
team_id PK FK
(Optional a own id witch is PK but why would you need that?)
```

--

```
USER_GROUP
user_id PK FK
group_id PK FK
(Again: Optional a own id witch is PK but why would you need that?)
```

And Constraints to check after adding  User(A),Group(B) to USER_GROUP if ther is a User(A),Team(X) entry in USER_TEAM  with X as the Team set in Group(B). And the other way arround if you delete a entry from the user_team relation. (So the User is also no longer member of the groups of that team.)

Comment: Philip you are reading my mind :). You explained what I have in mind. Other solution would be that every team would have at least one group where all users that belongs to that team are in. Kritner, do you agree? Thanks for brainstorming with me.